# Is it a strong anti-pattern to use a Floating Action Button in an iOS app?

Tags: ios, material-design, actions

Floating Action Buttons - invented by the Google Material Design Team - are rather popular on Android. Apple's closest equivalent are perhaps an action icon at top-right or the bottom Tool Bar pattern - which won't play nicely with a persistent Tab Bar.

I'm working on an iOS app that has a very strong, prominent 'hallmark action' that needs to stand out and be accessible from the app's main screen. Should I use a Floating Action Button in iOS?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*Edit (2022): Material Design has been a strong voice in application design for many years now, and many iOS users will have seen the FAB pattern. FABs are not a core experience to iOS and can still confuse users who don't regularly use your app.*

TL;DR: I consider the Floating Action Button (FAB) to be the most polarizing element of Material Design, and **generally wouldn't recommend a floating action button for use in an iOS application**.

The principle is still sound: **provide a strong call-to-action element (CTA) to guide your users**. Apple tends to favor the top-right interaction, but I consider the play/shuffle button in Spotify to be a good example of a non-toolbar interaction (see below). It helps that it has high discoverability (easily understood wording rather than abstract icons). Other apps (Instagram, Tumblr) use the central icon of the Tab Bar to focus the user on a primary action (which might be relevant for your use).

The FAB is probably the least generic component in the language and tends to make all implementations look like they were made by Google (which works great on Android). It's an abstract concept with low discoverability, which works fine for Android since it's part of the OS. You're taught to use it as part of the onboarding for the device.

If your target audience is iOS, where it isn't commonly understood, then you're increasing the complexity for new users. Ultimately there is nothing stopping you from using a FAB, but **you should probably expect users to not know what it is, or how to use it on sight.**

[image: Spotify Shuffle button]

*Strong shuffle CTA, with clear statement of what will happen when selected.*

[image: Instagram post button on Tab Bar]

*Example of how Instagram moved away from a strong CTA (probably to focus on the feed over posting...)*

Comment: _It's an abstract concept with low discoverability_ Can you explain this? A FAB doesn't need to be discovered, it's always there and it always does one defined obvious action.

Comment: It's been a while since I've had to think about this. And I wouldn't say that FABs are as unfamiliar in iOS as they were in 2016. That said, I still think you have to learn what they do by committing to do the action before you know what it does. This isn't always a great experience (it might put cautious users off or push them into user journeys they're not ready for). Essentially still the same advice: use them _intentionally and thoughtfully_.

Answer (score 16):

New in iOS 11 you can find the Floating Action Button within the Notes App. If Apple uses them, you could definitely use them too.

[image: FAB in iOS 11 Notes]

Comment: Hi and welcome to UX.SE *cornr*! Unfortunately, this does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to [comment on any post](http://ux.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: Why is it not providing an answer to the question? If Apple uses FAB it is at least an Example for "you could use a FAB"

Comment: You’re not explaining why...

Comment: Well I am grateful for it!

Comment: By the way, I for one dislike the new floating (+) button in iOS Notes app. It's always in my way.

Comment: This is a perfectly valid answer.

Comment: @BennySkogberg "Is it an anti-pattern?" "No." "Why?" "Because Apple does it too." Seems to me this perfectly answers the question and with a reasonable explanation. Especially considering copying Apple is a very good strategy when it comes to designing iOS apps.

Comment: Update: It isn't there anymore in iOS 13 (or I haven't found it)

Comment: Its still there in iOS 13. It shows if you close (x) the bar above the keyboard while editing a note

Comment: I'm not sure this is still present in iOS 15

Comment: Just checked it is still there in iOS 16 (iPhone 12 mini) if you close the bar above the keyboard. Its not there on my iPad.

Answer (score 10):

If you compare GMAIL user interface itself on the Apple and Android mobiles, the UI is a bit different (user pics and checkboxes - on the left-hand side, etc.).

For the IOS, the GMAIL takes a different design pattern for FAB or button compared to the Android Design, but it still stands out. You may want to consider this design for your app. Frankly speaking, I am not sure why GMAIL avoided FAB on the IOS.

I got an Apple mobile 6S with me and I have compared with another android mobile to cross check and confirm the UI, which is exactly same as the screenshots provided below.

[image]

Source of the images: 
https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpttrns.com%2Fapplications%2F370&psig=AFQjCNFIfKmNmucdvJpli_i9xgtqO1zpgg&ust=1476535412516119

http://www.lifehack.org/articles/technology/finally-20-productivity-apps-that-will-ensure-efficiency.html

Comment: The Google Inbox Gmail app uses the FAB in the iOS version.

Comment: ummmm what's this then https://storage.googleapis.com/gweb-uniblog-publish-prod/images/Gmail_iOS_Hero_Image_11.7.16.2e16d0ba.fill-1440x810.jpg

Comment: @pete that would be an updated interface, released after the answer an comment were posted. No need to get snarky.